# How to calculate a field in access then use a lookup to bring back related information

Tags: ms-access

I'm setting up a database in the school I teach to track progress of students. When they arrive at our (high) school they have two scores for their Maths and English tests - these are numeric levels (e.g. 3,4,5,6 etc.). I then need to average them then round down (e.g. a student with a 4 in Maths and a 5 in English would have a 'average' grade of 4) which I have a achieved using an Int expression in a calculated field. However I now need to run a report which shows what grade at GCSE (tests taken at age 16 in the UK) they should achieve. For example a student which comes in on an average grade 3 should achieve a letter grade D at GCSE ( 4 > C , 5 > B etc.). I have another table with these equivalencies in them but Access won't let me form a relationship with a calculated field. I am in the process of migrating from Excel to Access (I would use Index/Match to achieve this on a spreadsheet) but have little comprehension of how this works in Access. Can anyone point me in the right direction of how this could be done?

Many thanks!

Comment: As you state in your question, you need a lookup. Therefore, the `DLookUp` function should do the trick. http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dlookup.php

Comment: Thanks! Would that be as another calculated field or as a query?

Comment: You can either use it straight on the control source of the textbox in your report that you use to display the grade, or in the query itself, before assigning it to the report. It works both ways.

Comment: Very useful advice, I ended up using the SQL in that link - I think I am more comfortable using that. The query now spits out the correct information! Muchas gracias.